# OpenJDK-11 issue while accessing Jaxb Jars packaged inside war/lib from tomcat/lib Jar

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, war, classnotfoundexception

We are having a custom utility jar in tomcat/lib folder. This custom utility needs access to Jaxb jars which is not part of Jdk-11. We already modified application dependencies to include Jaxb jars & these are now getting packaged in our WAR/WEB-INF/lib folder.

Is there a way to access these JAXB jars packaged inside war/WEB-INF/lib folder from tomcat/lib Jar?

Probably both are loaded by different class loaders & this may not be possible, but we do not want to copy these Jaxb jars to tomcat/lib to avoid duplicating them.

Also moving custom utility jar from tomcat/lib to war/WEB-INF/lib does not looks an option here as its being managed by another team & multiple teams/applications are sharing it.

Comment: No. Drop them with your jar in tomcat/lib

Comment: Thankyou @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen for quick response.